# How to extract part of filename in an excel cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office

I need to extract part of a file name in an excel cell. 
The name of the file is " AOL Report Sheet 01-08-2019 ". I would like the date part to be referenced in the cell.

Comment: Do you have file name in Cell or you want to access from system?

Comment: It isn't clear what you need to do.  You talk about extracting the date, but the last part sounds like you want to specify the date in a cell and then have the filename incorporate it by referencing that cell.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

If the file name format is just as you show, with the date at the end separated by a space, then try:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```

which returns the last space-separated substring from any string.

Comment: Exactly Ron, and when it's always formatted like this, it would be the last 10 chars from the right.

Comment: @JvdV That would be even simpler if that is indeed what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

If your date will always be to the right and 10 characters long, you could use a simpler formula:

```
=RIGHT(A1,10)
```

This isn't as reusable as Ron's answer though. You could consider for an extra space at the end by adding "Trim" to the reference, like this:

```
=RIGHT(TRIM(A1),10)
```